# Visual Studio Code Extension similar to "CSS PEEK" for Cpp

Tags: c++

Is there any extension for VSC similar to the integrated "Ctrl + mouse hover" future which allow user to edit the definition of variable/function/etc. in a pop out windows without leaving the current page? Like "CSS PEEK" but not work HTML/CSS projects.
Any suggestions is highly appreciated!

Comment: Is that not included with the C/C++ extension?

Comment: Yes, but when the definition and declaration point is in another file, it will open that file. So, I want to just stay on my code and edit that part without leaving current code.